# Usage of final nun with kamatz

Tags: hebrew, tanach, language

Frequently, in Tanac"h, the 3rd person female plural uses an end nun with a kamatz ןָ rather than nun-heh נָה.

Is there any reasoning of preference of one usage vs. the other?

Comment: I count 3 instances of ןָ in Ruth. What is your assessment based on? Did you search through Tanakh?

Comment: A quick count gives 45 with נָה and 26 with ןָ in the Torah (I could be off by a few). Also, of the more than 200 in נ״ך, there are (I count) 13 with ןָ.

Comment: @magick is there a particular word that it shows up on that comes up a lot in the same story in Genesis for instance?

Comment: @DoubleAA From the Torah, nine of them come from תהיין, and 8 of those are from Gen/Ex (and mostly Ex 25-28) (the outlier is Deut 21:15; תהיינה appears 10 times in Torah, all in Lev and Num).  Two are ותשקין (Gen 19), two are ותשתחוין (Gen 33, 37), and two are ותאמרן (Ex 1-2), while the rest are isolated occurrences.

Comment: Why ךָ instead of כָה?